# How to hide formula result until data is entered in at least 5 of the 7 cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have a question. Is there a way I can hide the formula result in C10 until data is entered in at least 5 of the 7 cells in column C? Please see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bfPz.jpg)
Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Great. This is what I've done. 
In formula cell C10:
=IF(COUNTBLANK(C3:C9)>=3,"",SUM(C3:C9))
It works! Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use something like this in cell C10:

```
=IF(COUNT(C3:C9)>=5,SUM(C3:C9),””)
```

This will sum the severity ratings only if there are at least 5 cells with numbers in the C3:C9 range. Otherwise, if less than 5 numbers are present then it returns a blank value.

(On a mobile phone so can’t double check it.)

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest two possible formula:*

[image]

---

- Formula in cell AE28:

  ```
  =IF(COUNTBLANK($AE$19:$AE$27)>=5,"Blank Cells are "&COUNTBLANK($AE$19:$AE$27),SUM($AE$19:$AE$27))
  ```

**N.B.** You may replace `"Blank Cells are "&COUNTBLANK($AE$19:$AE$27)` with `""` or any TEXT message.

- Formula in cell AE29:

  ```
  =IF(SUMPRODUCT(--($AE$19:$AE$27=""))>=5,"",SUM($AE$19:$AE$27))
  ```

**N.B.**

- With SUMPRODUCT the double Hyphen symbol `–`, produces 1s as TRUE and 0s as FALSE, and SUMPRODUCT sums these digits to total count of Blank or Empty cells.

[image]

---

- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.